# How to Fix Firebase SignIn

Tags: firebase, flutter

I can login using google signin in debug mode. 
I have also tried building an apk like `flutter build apk --release` and the signin also worked.
I then have proceeded to `flutter build appbundle` and upload the said bundle to the PlayStore. now none of my users can login into the app.

I ran `gradlew signingReport` 
and a bund of sha1 keys were shown. Most of them where repetition so I used both the different ones that showed on the screen (one for debug other for release) and added them to my firebase config project

When someone tries to login the google popup showing the gAccounts on the phone appear for you to choose one or use a different one. when you press the one you want it disapears but it doesn't log you in. what am I missing?

Comment: Yes, You need to add sha1 key on Firebase. And this sha1 key is generated using the released Keystore.

Comment: I literaly said in the post that i added both the debug and release sha-1 keys to firestore :) @PraneethDhanushkaFernando

Comment: @Sunny I used gradlw , am i doing it wrong? can you tell me how to use the release keystore?

Answer (score 0):

This is for the debug sha1 key **MAC**

```
keytool -exportcert -list -v -alias androiddebugkey -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore
```

if you wants to generate the relase sha1 key Just replace **androiddebugkey** with your **alisa name** and **~/.android/debug.keystore** with you **keystore** file path

For e.g.

```
keytool -exportcert -list -v -alias tashmania -keystore /Users/SunnySaini/Documents/git/tashmania/app/jks/tashmania.jks
```

Comment: will try this tonight, However, the sha-1 I used did say "release" so i'm assuming it's the same. will try it ASAP and let you know

Comment: as I said, gradlw exports the exact same key. It doesn't work.